# PictureBox BackgroundImage property doesn't work

Tags: c#

I've set the backgroundImage property, and still the image covers all the UI, what am I doing wrong? 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you set the `Image` as well?

Comment: @OskarKjellin Yes, Image and BackgroundImage, both of them

Comment: You need to clear `Image` if you want the background image to be visible

Comment: @OskarKjellin You mean by setting it to none? because I can't "Clear" it, the button is gray. I tried setting it to none, but it's still not working

Comment: @OskarKjellin Oh wait.. it works actually, I was trying to figure the problem for like 30 minutes, I had to drug the buttons again!! dammit.. Thank you man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not providing enough information, but possible scenarios are:

1. The `PictureBox` is set to cover the entire form
2. You've not set the `PictureBox`'s `BackgroundImage` property but the one of the form itself
3. You have set the `PictureBox` to stretch the image (goes together with 1.)

Why are you setting `BackgroundImage` at all? Usually you put a `PictureBox` on the form, assign the image and make sure that it has the appropriate size (or stretches, which I assume your's is doing). Usually you don't need the `BackgroundImage` property to display an image in the `PictureBox`.

Comment: I know some people would say that this question should not be answered at all due to a massive lack of information. I still think that my answer might point the poster in the right direction, which is why I'm posting an answer instead of a comment...

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, Image and BackgroundImage, both of them

I assume you've set the `BackgroundImage` for the form and are now trying to clear the `BackgroundImage` of the `PictureBox`, that's why the "Clear" button is grayed out and that's why you see both of them.

Go ahead and select the form first by clicking somewhere on it where there is no other control, and then go to the `BackgroundImage` property and clear it.